# Get dynamically generated image

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

I'm trying to use python selenium to download the large scale image from the amazon product page. Example [https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-UN65RU7100FXZA-Flat-UHD-Smart/dp/B07NC96MBL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NC96MBL). It only appears when you hover the mouse over the small image and click. Is it possible to use mouse position somehow?

I have tried this, which doesn't work:

```
browser.get("https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-UN65RU7100FXZA-Flat-UHD-Smart/dp/B07NC96MBL")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[8]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li[4]").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='landingImage']").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='magnifierLens']").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/img").click()
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First click all the thumbnails, then extract the url of high res images like shown below. Have to click all thumbnails or else the high res images won't be loaded in to DOM.

```
browser.get("https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-UN65RU7100FXZA-Flat-UHD-Smart/dp/B07NC96MBL")
thumbnails=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li.a-spacing-small.item.imageThumbnail.a-declarative")
for thumbnail in thumbnails
  thumbnail.click()

highResLinks=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='imgTagWrapper']//img")
for highResLink in highResLinks
  print(highResLink.get_attribute("data-old-hires"))
```

Comment: This only prints one link. Is it possible to get it to print all hi-res links?

Comment: Were you able to click all the thumbnails in the page first. Using the code above? You would be able to get all the images only after you click each one of the thumbnails.

Comment: Yes, it clicks all the thumbnails, but only extracts one hi-res image.

Comment: Edited my answer. Ran above code, it gets all the high-res image links. It was not clicking the thumbnails before. Now it does. Check and let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: Yes, I managed to get it to work after some debugging. How did you get the //div[@class='imgTagWrapper']//img ??